# Initialize the value of a arraylist

Tags: android, database, arraylist

I can't understand what is wrong in my code . I am getting error in myAddressUniqueness. don't know why.Before i have tried it with string data type but got the same error. It is saying java.null exception.

```
ArrayList<String>  myAddressUniqueness = null;
    String name = "hello";

    if (indexBody < 0 || !cursor.moveToFirst())
        return;

    smsList.clear();

    do {
        // int cursorPostion = cursor.getPosition();

        String address;
        String msgStr = cursor.getString(indexBody);
        String senderNumber = cursor.getString(indexAddr);
        Log.d("Name : ", senderNumber);
        // String name = cursor.getString(cursor
        // .getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));
        // Log.d("Name : ",name);

        if (name != null) {
            address = name;
        } else {
            address = senderNumber;
        }
        Log.d("Address: ", address);
        flag = 1;
        //Log.e("Number: ", addressUniqueness.length + "");

        for (j = 0; j < myAddressUniqueness.size(); j++) {
            if (myAddressUniqueness.contains(address)) {
                flag = 0;
                break;
            }

        }

        if (flag == 1) {
            myAddressUniqueness.add(new String(address));
            i++;

            String str = "Sender: " + address + "\n";
            smsList.add(str);

        }

        // TODO Auto-generated catch block

    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
```

Comment: Can you point out, at which line you are getting the NullPointerException?

Comment: problem solved :) . it is a foolish think.. i haven't initialize the arraylist

Answer (score 2):

Change your declaration to

`ArrayList<String>  myAddressUniqueness = new ArrayList<String>();`

You have it initialized to `null`. This will instantiate it then you can add data to it.

Answer (score 0):

You should instantiate `myAddressUniqueness` by `myAddressUniqueness = new ArrayList<String>()` before using it.